# Making a character variable equal to a nill value in delphi

Tags: delphi, char

I am creating a programme where I am searching for vowels within a string, and after they have been found, the vowels need to be removed from the string.

```
 mystring := 'August'   ;

{if mystring[1] IN ['A','E','I','O','U'] ;}
for k := 1 to length(mystring) DO
BEGIN
if mystring[K] IN ['a','e','i','o','u']
then mystring[k] := ''
```

but the error

> Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'String' " appears

**What can i do to delete the vowels from my string?**

Comment: Empty string `''` is not a char. It's, uhm, empty string. Which version of Delphi are you using ? Could you add a Delphi version tag into your question ?

Comment: Use #0 instead of '' for `then mystring[k] := ''`

Comment: @Alexandr No, don't do that. Think what happens then when you put the string into, say, an edit control.

Comment: I would use my favorite [`pointer char technique`](http://pastebin.com/KjTGSgth) :-) [I know many people hate it]

Comment: @TLama I rather like that approach.

Comment: @TLama which is *not any faster* than a version that not uses PChar but a for-to loop over the string (as David presented). It more smells like "I heared pointers are faster, so I use them!"

Comment: @Stefan, I don't care about speed. I just like that way. Nothing more or less.

Comment: @TLama Ok, I don't like it - I am still traumatized by code like that when we migrated our product from Delphi 7 to XE which either was slower than the pointerless version, was buggy (with unicode) or just simply unreadable (and often a combination of these).

Comment: @Stefan, it's always your choice. Yes, it is less readable, but it's ANSI/Unicode compatible. You've just had it badly written.

Comment: @TLama: Nice code, really. Just one thing: it will fail when `Value` contains #0 chars, which is completely legal with Delphi strings. You test against #0 in the loop. Bad idea.

Comment: @JensG, yes, that's right. Me (and many times also RTL) expect that you're not going to have strings containing #0 in the middle (I forgot to warn about it). But if it's a bad idea depends on what you're going to do with that string. For instance, if you were going to show a string with a #0 char in the middle in an edit box, you would fail because the Windows API will cut off the string behind #0. So, the same I could say about using #0 in the middle ;-) It depends, but yes, it is a weakness...

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is a *null* character value. You are trying to use the empty string, which is an entity with zero length. But there is no character than has zero length. The *null* character value that you are looking for simply does not exist.

Another way to see this is to consider what `Length(mystring)` is at the end of your loop. No matter what characters you assign with `mystring[k] := ...`, the length of `mystring` is never modified.

So, you could make a new string instead of modifying the existing one. For example:

```
var 
  new: string;
  len: Integer;
....
SetLength(new, Length(mystring));
len := 0;
for i := 1 to Length(mystring) do
begin
  if not (mystring[i] in ['a','e','i','o','u']) then
  begin
    inc(len);
    new[len] := mystring[i];
  end;
end;
SetLength(new, len);
mystring := new;
```

Or you could make repeated calls to `StringReplace`:

```
mystring := StringReplace(mystring, 'a', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
mystring := StringReplace(mystring, 'e', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
//etc.
```

This version using `StringReplace` is slower than the first approach.

Yet another approach would be to operate in place:

```
var 
  len: Integer;
....
len := 0;
for i := 1 to Length(mystring) do
begin
  if not (mystring[i] in ['a','e','i','o','u']) then
  begin
    inc(len);
    mystring[len] := mystring[i];
  end;
end;
SetLength(mystring, len);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or this one:

```
VAR
  I : Cardinal;

BEGIN
  I:=1;
  WHILE I<=LENGTH(MyString) DO
    IF MyString[I] IN ['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'] THEN
      DELETE(MyString,I,1)
    ELSE
      INC(I)
END;
```

David's code is probably faster, but this one doesn't need any additional string. Also, this one also takes care of upper-case vowels (if that's what you want).

Comment: This needs an additional string every time you call `Delete`

Comment: Really? That seems a bit inefficient by the compiler. I would move the characters in-place (if the reference count = 1). Room for optimization of the compiler, then...

Answer (score 1):

Just another suggestion for your evaluation:

```
for i := 1 to Length(mystring) do
  if mystring[i] in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] then
    mystring[i] := #1;
mystring := StringReplace(mystring, #1, '', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

The ideia is to replace all the vowels by the character **#1** (**#0** doesn't work). The loop does that. Then, all **#1** in the string are removed by replacing them by an empty string, what is achieved by the function **StringReplace**.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like :

```
localStr:=mystring;
mystring:='';
if ... then mystring:=mystring+localStr[i];
```

example

```
mystring:= 'August';
...

var
localStr: string;
i       : Integer;
begin
localStr:=mystring;
mystring:='';
for i := 1 to Length(localStr) do if NOT ((localStr[i] in ['a','e','i','o','u'])) then
              mystring:=mystring+localStr[i];
end;
```

Result mystring : `Agst`

---

For the experts :

Never thought the `StringReplace` with only one sign, is so slow.
If string is 474000 bytes. This test takes 2 minutes and 5 seconds.

```
User        Code in short
--------------------------------------------

David       inc(len) | new[len] := mystring[i] | SetLength(new, len)
David 2.    inc(len) | mystring[len] := mystring[i] | SetLength(mystring, len)
TLama       if not (C^ in CharSet) then | localStr[I] := C^ | Inc(I)
Me          localStr:=mystring | mystring:='' | mystring:=mystring+localStr[i]
AlexSc      mystring := StringReplace(mystring, #1, '', [rfReplaceAll])
HeartWare   I := 1                  | WHILE I<=LENGTH(MyString) DO  | DELETE(MyString,I,1) | INC(I)
 " DEC(I)   I := LENGTH(MyString)   | WHILE I > 0 DO                | DELETE(MyString,I,1) | DEC(I)
```

*HeartWare DEC(I) is only to show that delete downto is faster*

The Test in seconds.

```
            length(mystring)--MB--------------------
            0.474       1.049       4.002       7.995       15.358      56.948
----------------------------------------------------                
Delphi 5 on XP
----------------------------------------------------            
TLama   :   0.003       0.016       0.047       0.078       0.172       0.687
David   :   0.003       0.016       0.047       0.093       0.192       0.765
David 2.:   0.003       0.016       0.063       0.109       0.219       0.875

Me      :   0.125       0.281       1.109       2.192       4.203
HeartWare:  27.284      131.057
 " DEC(I):  21.793      108.406
AlexSc  :   143.723     break > 8 min.

Rad XE4 on vista
----------------------------------------------------            
TLama   :   0.003       0.032       0.068       0.139       0.194
David   :   0.003       0.032       0.068       0.146       0.203
Me      :   0.094       0.172       0.481       0.921       1.576
HeartWare:  23.056      119.076
 " DEC(I):  17.519      103.319
AlexSc  :   125.082     break > 8 min.
```

Comment: @TLama : Tested your Code it's a little bit slower. (the short version `CharSet = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];`)

Comment: How about David's second entry (in-place)? I would guess that one is the fastest (by a narrow margin to his first entry).

Comment: @HeartWare : 1. entry, `mystring = 0.474 MB` . 2. entry `mystring = 1.049 MB` .

Comment: @moskito-x, interesting benchmark! I don't think that pointer char iteration is faster anymore (for a longer time). I don't know why, but I just like it... But anyway, I think I have found the source where I might losing my time. Try [`this version`](http://pastebin.com/rYQPyvP4). With that version I must win :-) Just don't forget to shorten the set of chars since as before I'm checking also capitals. [+1ed]

Comment: @moskito-x, strange how the `CharInSet` function slows the execution down. Thanks anyway!

Comment: There are two fast variants in my answer. Did you test both?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Have with your second solution a new test and a new 56,948 MB column. Your 2. solution is slightly faster.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Apology: I accidentally did the test with my 2. version. With this I have tested the speed when already all `a, e, i, o, u` were removed. Do the test again correctly, will let you know when I'm done.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : I can not explain, but your second solution is slower. I also thought this would be faster. Only tested on XP / Delphi 5

Comment: It will be faster for snall strings and slower for large ones I predict