# Cannot remove `Null Characters` from a string

Tags: delphi, null, character, delphi-xe4

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580662/how-to-read-a-text-file-that-contains-null-character-in-delphi) couple months ago. Thanks to [Rob Kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33732/rob-kennedy) I could load my whole text into a `Richedit` **BUT I couldn't remove `Null chars`.** I could load my text because I used `Stream`.

---

Now in this code:

```
var
  strm : TMemorystream;
  str  : UTF8string;
  ss   : TStringstream;

begin
  strm := tmemorystream.Create;

  try
    strm.LoadFromFile('C:\Text.txt');
    setstring(str,PAnsichar(strm.Memory),strm.Size);
    str := StringReplace(str, #0, '', [rfReplaceAll]);  //This line doesn't work at all
    ss  := tstringstream.Create(str);
    Richedit1.Lines.LoadFromStream(ss);
  finally
    strm.Free;
    ss.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I converted `TMemorystream` to `string` to remove `Null Chars` with `StringReplace()` and then converted it again to `TStringstream` to load it with `Richedit.lines.LoadFromStream`.

But my problem is that I can't remove `Null Character` using `StringReplace()`. I can replace other characters but not `#0`.

Is there any way to remove null charcters directly in `TMemorystream` and load it into a `Richedit`? How? If it's not possible or it's very complex, how can I remove them when I convert my text to `string`?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) input one character 2) if it isn't `NUL` then output it, else discard it 3) go to step 1.

Comment: Why did you accept my answer before if it didn't work? Note that I've updated my answer to mention the shortcoming of `StringReplace` and link to [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3685055/33732) that accomplishes the same task.

Comment: The real question is - why does the file have nulls in it to begin with? A UTF-8 encoded text file should not have any nulls in it, so the file is likely not UTF-8 to begin with. And this code is horribly inefficient with all of the UTF8->UTF16->UTF8->UTF16 conversions.

Comment: @RobKennedy I accepted your answer because you solved my problem. Not because of removing null chars but because of using stream instead of loading file.

Comment: @RemyLebeau When I change `UTF8string` to `string` then the text will become unreadable.

Comment: @Sky Trial and error is never a very good policy. Remy is encouraging you to understand. I agree with him. I personally just answered the question that you asked, but most likely true enlightenment will be found by following Remy's council.

Comment: @Sky: I was not suggesting you simply replace `UTF8String`, I was suggesting you might need to replace the entire logic as a whole. If you have to jump through so many hoops just to load a text file, then you are loading it the wrong way to begin with. Text files are not this complex to load, which suggests the file is either written wrong, or is not a simple text file to begin with despite its file extension.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your suggestion. Can you please explain more about it? - Yeah before this, I tried to load my text (That is actually a web page source) with simple ways. But they didn't work (unusual chars, encoding...). So I had to use this code instead. And as you see in my profile most of my question are about this. Texts, Encoding, Indy and...

Comment: @Sky: A webpage has a charset associated with it, which is specified either in the HTTP `Content-Type` header or in the HTML itself via a `<meta>` tag. You have to use the correct charset when decoding the data to Unicode. You can't load the data using whatever charset you feel like it. You will lose data that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can see, all searching/replacing utilities, at one time or other, cast the input to a PChar, which '#0' is the termination character. Hence they never go past the string part that's before the first Null. You may need to devise your own mechanism. Just a quick example:

```
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Assert(str <> '');
  i := 1;
  while i <= Length(str) do
    if str[i] = #0 then
      Delete(str, i, 1)
    else
      Inc(i);
```

Replacing in the stream would similarly involve testing each character and then adjusting the stream accordingly before moving on after you decide to delete one.

Comment: You could be in your answer, point out the "delete" should only be used with small amounts of data . [compare delete vs others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460211/making-a-character-variable-equal-to-a-nill-value-in-delphi)

Comment: @moskito - It would seem so, yes. IMO, though, explaining the reason and giving a simple example should suffice.

Comment: @Sertac I think that ought to be the case. Sadly the reality is that people who don't know any better will blindly use whatever code you post. A disclaimer stating, "don't use this code in production since it thrashes the heap" would be good enough for me. Even then though I'm many folk would ignore the warning!

Comment: @David - I think I was mistaken that the poster does have any interest whatsoever about the reason of the behavior. All that's really asked seems to be *write the code*, in which case your answer is the only alternative in fact. I don't have any problem with your answer being selected, what bothered me was the fact that I'm not always able to make out what *kind* of an answer is required.

Comment: I agree. Your answer explains why `StringReplace` behaves as it does. And as such it should be accepted. It really doesn't look as though the asked has any interest at all in understanding what's going on and that is the fundamental reason why this problem is still extant.

Answer (score 10):

Sertac's answer is accurate and you should accept it. If performance is important, and you have a large string with frequent instances of the null character then you should try to reduce the number of heap allocations. Here is how I would implement this:

```
function RemoveNull(const Input: string): string;
var
  OutputLen, Index: Integer;
  C: Char;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Input));
  OutputLen := 0;
  for Index := 1 to Length(Input) do
  begin
    C := Input[Index];   
    if C <> #0 then
    begin
      inc(OutputLen);
      Result[OutputLen] := C;
    end;
  end;
  SetLength(Result, OutputLen);
end;
```

If you want to do it directly in the memory stream, then you can do it like this:

```
procedure RemoveNullFromMemoryStream(Stream: TMemoryStream);
var
  i: Integer;
  pIn, pOut: PByte;
begin
  pIn := Stream.Memory;
  pOut := pIn;
  for i := 0 to Stream.Size-1 do
  begin
    if pIn^ <> 0 then
    begin
      pOut^ := pIn^;
      inc(pOut);
    end;
    inc(pIn);
  end;
  Stream.SetSize(NativeUInt(pOut)-NativeUInt(Stream.Memory));
end;
```

Comment: Okay. Accepted Sertac's answer :)