# Error in Reading a CSV file using Delphi 5

Tags: delphi, csv

I am having a problem in reading CSV file using Delphi 5.

File contents are

```
1. a,b,c,d //1st line
2. ,,,,e,f //2nd line
3. n,d,e,f //3rd line
4. a,c,e //4th line
```

I am using following code to read

```
var
  respCSV : TStringList  ;
  sLine : string ;
  tf : TextFile;
begin
  respCSV := TStringList.Create ;
  // prompt the user for a file-name then load into a string list
  with openDialog1 do
  begin
    FileName := '';
    if Execute then
    begin
      AssignFile(tf, FileName);
      Reset(tf);
      while not eof(tf) do
      begin
        sLine := '' ;
        ReadLn(tf,sLine); //In Debug/Evaluate it shows 2nd row perfectly 
        showMessage(sLine); //but in showMessage Here 2nd row is showing as
        //null, While it has nulls only in start
        respCSV.Add(sLine); //Adding 2nd row as empty row

      end; //end while
    end;//end if
  end;//end with
```

2nd row in File starts with Null ,,,,e,f.. so it is showing all line as null

Comment: What do you mean by Null, is it character null ie #0? If that is the case, you must realize that #0 is considered as a string terminator. That's the reason why you get an empty string for second line. If I where you, I would find out why there are null characters in the CSV file, this seems not correct. You can filter out null characters from a string, here is a [hint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18802086/800214).

Comment: Yes, There is #0 i.e. the null terminator character. I exported this csv file from Survey Monkey. It is kinda survey response sheet in csv format.

Comment: Thanks... Filtering out null characters worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is being read correctly. The string variable `sLine` holds the full line. However, `ShowMessage` treats a null character, `#0`, as being a terminator and does not display anything beyond that.

So, there is nothing (much) wrong with your code to read the file. Initialising `sLine` to the empty string is pointless since you assign it in the next line. And you don't close the file when you have finished reading it.

Comment: respCSV.LoadFromFile(FileName); loads all four lines in a single line...i.e. respCSV.count result in 1 instead of 4

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The `TStrings.LoadFrom...()` methods support bare-CR, bare-LF, and CRLF line breaks, and always have, even in Delphi 5 (I just checked).  But what they **don't** support, and have never supported (even in modern versions), is embedded nulls. If `LoadFrom...()` encounters a null, it will stop loading and exit immediately. And since the second line starts with a null, only the first line gets loaded, that is why the `Count` is 1.